# Hide admin sub menus menus via acl

Tags: magento2, permissions, acl

I am looking to disable menus for certain users present within 
Stores->Configuration->sales->Checkout Totals Sort Order .
I have added their values in acl.xml But it does not work.

[How to disable or hide the core ACL resources in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101700/how-to-disable-or-hide-the-core-acl-resources-in-magento-2)